# How to get json response from inside the page from Webview(I get a response with user-agent)?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, instagram-api, user-agent

[Json i want to get is here, I want to keep this json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtYUW.png)

```
private void logData(WebView view, final String url) {
    view.evaluateJavascript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()", new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String value) {


            Ion.with(context).load(url).asString().setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {

                    if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {

                        int maxLogSize = 1000;
                        for (int i = 0; i <= result.length() / maxLogSize; i++) {
                            int start = i * maxLogSize;
                            int end = (i + 1) * maxLogSize;
                            end = Math.min(end, result.length());
                            Log.v("LoggedHTML", result.substring(start, end));
                        }

                    }
                }
            });


        }
    })
}
```

this code gives me the html document of the page, i want to print json

Comment: Finally ı found the solution,

I changed this,
view.evaluateJavascript("document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString()"
with this;
 view.loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                        "(document.body.innerText);");

Answer (score 0):

```
WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        wb.loadUrl("javascript:HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                "('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
    }
};
wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
wb.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
wb.loadUrl("http://pqrs.abcde.com/facebook");
wb.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlViewer");
```

Comment: I have already added this, this is give me html documentation